# What do the memberOf<Relationship> and objectIn<Relationship>AtIndex:(NSUInteger)index do?

Tags: core-data

I have just tripped over some methods on an NSManagedObject via XCode's code completion, and I'm trying to figure out what they do.

I have an entity called A. It has a to-one relationship with B, and a to-many relationship with C. Code completion offers the following method signatures:

```
- (A *) memberOfB:(A *)object 
- (A *) memberOfC:(A *)object

- (A *) objectInBAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
- (A *) objectInCAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

"memberOf" sounds like it would mean "is object a member of the B.A set?", but that would return a boolean, and take a B as the argument. Totally stumped on that one.

"objectInXAtIndex" sounds like it might return something from the set B.A, except of course that sets are not ordered and don't take indexes (these aren't indexed relationships). Not to mention that it doesn't make sense to have something like that be an instance method on A.

Anybody know? Haven't found any leads at all googling or searching here.

Comment: How did you manage to get these methods via code completion? That did not work for me.

Comment: @MartinR I see the memberOf if I type in "-(A *) m", and then the full list if I backspace the m.

Comment: Strange, does not work for me ... Can you Ctrl-click -> "Jump to Definition" in Xcode on that method? Where does it jump to?

Comment: Nope, doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: @MartinR FWIW I'm running Xcode version 4.5.2 (4G2008a).

Comment: Yes, same here. Do you use mogenerator or something that might create prototypes for these accessor functions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22273/discussion-between-sasha-and-martin-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This are (dynamically) generated accessor methods for Key-Value Coding compliance,
see [Key-Value Coding Accessor Methods](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/AccessorConventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002174-BAJEAIEE) in the "Key-Value Coding Programming Guide":

> In order to be key-value coding compliant for a mutable ordered
>   to-many relationship you must implement the following methods:
>   ...
>   `-objectIn<Key>AtIndex:` or `-<key>AtIndexes:`. One of these methods must be implemented. They correspond to the `NSArray` `methods objectAtIndex:`
>   and `objectsAtIndexes:`
>   ...
>   In order to support read-only access to an unordered to-many relationship, you would implement the following methods:
>   ...
>   `-memberOf<Key>:`. Required. This method is the equivalent of the `NSSet` method `member:`